Probability That Your Age is Equal to the Current Year Minus Your Birth Year
This problem arose as a thought I had: When someone tells me when they were born, for example, in 2001, I often will say they are 2024-2001=23 years old. Of course, this is not always correct and is dependent on the day they were born - if their birthday has passed in the current year yet or not. I was curious how likely it is for the approach above to get you the right answer. I have posted an answer below, and my main purpose for this post is just having this problem exist, but also verification, improvements, etc. are welcome and encouraged. With that said, it is important to note the assumptions I have made:
I am assuming that you are equally likely to be born on any day of the year, which is (interestingly) not true. Also, I have not considered leap years, so there should certainly be a better approach to factor this in.
This could perhaps be an interesting problem for grade school students, and I have tried to explain my process in an attainable way.

The rough thought is of course that it is 50%: if you do this earlier in the year, then it is likely they haven't had their birthday yet (so now the subtraction methods fails) while later in the year, it is more likely they have had their birthday (so now it works). In particular, if you assume any day of the year is equally likely for anyone's birthday, if you are 40% of the way through the year, then there is a 40% chance their birthday has passed ... and so in the end it all averages to 50%.  As the more careful answer below explains, it is actually a little above 50% ... but not by much.

@Bram28 My approach and thoughts exactly! In the end we see that our problem can be modeled by the equation $y=\frac{x+1}{2x}$, with x being the number of days in a year, so 1/2 (50%) actually ends up being the limit, haha

To get some grounding, we can consider the extreme cases first. Someone born on January 1st would satisfy this equation every day of the year, 365/365 days. On the flip side, someone born on December 31st would satisfy this equation only one day out of the year (Dec. 31), so 1/365 days. This paints a clear picture of what the in-between birthdays get us. January 2nd would be 364/365 days, January 3rd 363/365 days, etc. Thus, we have:
$$\frac{365}{365}+\frac{364}{365}+...+\frac{1}{365}$$
added, as you can only be born on one day. Now, if you know the formula for the sum of the first n numbers, you can condense the numerator, but suppose you don't:
$$\frac{365}{365}+\frac{364}{365}+...+\frac{1}{365}=\frac{365+364+...+1}{365}$$
If you remember that famous Gauss tale, we can apply a similar organizing process here. For ease of understanding, allow me to arrange what we have as:
$$\frac{365}{365}+\frac{364+363+...+1}{365}$$
Now, as 364 is even, we can pair the numbers in the numerator of the fraction on the right as: $$\frac{365}{365}+\frac{364+363+...+1}{365}=\frac{365}{365}+\frac{364+1}{365}+\frac{363+2}{365}+...+\frac{183+182}{365}$$
And since each of those sums are 365, we see that:
$$\frac{365}{365}+\frac{364+1}{365}+\frac{363+2}{365}+...+\frac{183+182}{365}=\frac{365\cdot 183}{365}=183$$
(compare this with the formula for the sum of the first n numbers!)
Now, as stated above, we are assuming that the likelihood of being born on any day is exactly the same. Thus, to get our final probability, we divide by 365:
$$\frac{183}{365}\approx .501369 \hspace{.2cm} \text{or} ~50.137 \% $$
And this makes intuitive sense: There is one birthday that holds for 365/365 days of the year, but there is of course no birthday that never holds, so averaging it out it should fall just slightly above 50%.
